# Connecting two nodes based on identical properties in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

New to Neo4j. My goal is to make a database with various csv sources. I have created node labels of "geochemistry" and "geospatial" to be linked with the "LABID" node via a common property. I have loaded in one dataset easily, and made the necessary connections with the ":LOCATED" relationship being defined as between the geospatial and LABID nodes.

However, moving on to the second csv source, I am a little confused. I have tried matching the new geospatial data (which have no current relationships) to another set of Lab IDs. Below is my current code:

```
MATCH (g:geospatial) WHERE NOT (g)-[:LOCATED]->(:LABID)
MATCH (l:LABID)
WHERE l.labid = g.Sample_ID
MERGE (g)-[r:LOCATED]->(l)
RETURN r
```

labid is a current property in LABID, and so is Sample_ID to the geospatial nodes.

After completing the above query, the output is "(no changes, no records)"

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Maybe you meant `WHERE NOT EXISTS((g)-[:LOCATED]->(:LABID))`?

Comment: Check is one of the ids is an integer and the other a string... that is a common problem

Comment: @TomažBratanič this was it. Thanks!